# Why am I getting a "Run-time error '1004'" when I use this code on one worksheet, but not another?

Tags: excel, vba, userform, error-code

First off, here are my two codes:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim LRow As Long
Dim Myarray As Variant

 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Mark1.LEADLISTDROPDOWN.Value)
 
 With ws
 LRow = .Range("BJ" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 
 Set rng = ws.Range("A:KH" & LRow)
 
 PopoutLeadListBox.RowSource = rng.Address(External:=True)
 
 End With
 
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim LRow As Long
Dim Myarray As Variant

 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SalesForm.BHSDLEADLISTSCOMBOBOXLF.Value)
 
 With ws
 LRow = .Range("S" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 
 Set rng = ws.Range("H2:Y" & LRow)
 
 PopoutLeadListBox.RowSource = rng.Address(External:=True)
 
 End With
 
End Sub
```

The first one is popping up the error code, saying Method Range of object worksheet has failed. The second works just fine. To my knowledge, the only things that differ are the size of the ranges and the objects selected.

I wrote this a while ago with help online, and I am having trouble retracing my steps. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistyping in this line

```vb
Set rng = ws.Range("A:KH" & LRow)
```

Define the Range in this way `Range("Ax:KH" & LRow)`

where `x` is a number of the row of the range's top left cell.

Comment: I didn't have that in the second code, what makes this one different?

Comment: This worked, by the way! Just wondering why for future reference

Comment: @cheese There you have "H2:Y" it contains the number 2. H corresponds to A.

Comment: OH MY GOD. I'm such a dummy. Thank you so much. I can't believe I looked past that like 10 times. You're the best!